# Duplicating raster layer using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have a repetitive process where I duplicate a raster layer twice so I have 3 instances and I can display hillshade, elevation, and contour styles - I'm trying to create a model to run this process for me, but can't seem to find a duplicate raster algorithm.

Am I missing something or is this not possible with model designer?

Comment: Very much possible using pyqgis, but that is no model. If you want I can show you how?

Comment: I'd be very interested in knowing how to do it with pyqgis, but I have no experience with it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pyqgis:

```
baselayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DEM')[0] #Change DEM to the name of your layer

for name, rend in [['hillshade', QgsHillshadeRenderer(baselayer.dataProvider(), 1, 315, 45)],
                   ['contour', QgsRasterContourRenderer(baselayer.dataProvider())]]:
    
    newlyr = QgsRasterLayer(baselayer.source(), baselayer.name()+'_'+name)
    newlyr.setRenderer(rend)
    
    if 'setContourInterval' in dir(rend): #If it has this method it's the contours
        rend.setContourInterval(50)
        rend.setContourSymbol(QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_style': 'solid', 'color': 'white'}))
    else: #if no it's the hillshade
        rend.setZFactor(3)
        rend.setOpacity(0.5)
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(newlyr)
```

[image]